# Stop flex boxes with text overlays overlapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a couple of flex boxes with the following behavior...
1) Flex box 1 displays image with text to right at wider screen resolutions
2) Flex box 2 displays image with text below at wider screen resolutions
3) Both Flex box 1 and 2 overlay text on top of images for smaller screen resolutions

So far my code below works for scenarios 1) and 2). However, for scenario 3) the images with text overlay overlap each other when I want them to be stacked above each other.

Any advice on how to resolve would be most appreciated.

Thanks
Peter

```css
.imgtxtrow {
  display: flex;
  position: relative; 
}

.imgtxtcol {
  display: flex;
  position: relative; 
  flex-direction: column;
}

.subitem {
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  padding: 25px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
.subitem {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
 </head>

 <body>

  <div class="imgtxtrow">
   <div class="subitem">
    <div class="picture">  
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/27/21/03/lone-tree-1934897_1280.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="subitem">
    <div class="text">  
     <h3>Some Text</h3>   
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div style="clear:both"></div> 
  
  </br></br>

  <div class="imgtxtcol">
   <div class="subitem">
    <div class="picture">  
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/27/21/03/lone-tree-1934897_1280.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="subitem">
    <div class="text">  
     <h3>Some Text</h3>   
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very straightforward with a little bit of positioning. You were targeting the wrong element in your media query.

```css
.imgtxtrow {
  display: flex;
  position: relative; 
}

.imgtxtcol {
  display: flex;
  position: relative; 
  flex-direction: column;
}

.subitem {
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  padding: 25px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
.text {
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
  
}
```

```html
<html>

 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
 </head>

 <body>

  <div class="imgtxtrow">
   <div class="subitem">
    <div class="picture">  
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/27/21/03/lone-tree-1934897_1280.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="subitem">
    <div class="text">  
     <h3>Some Text</h3>   
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div style="clear:both"></div> 
  
  </br></br>

  <div class="imgtxtcol">
   <div class="subitem">
    <div class="picture">  
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/27/21/03/lone-tree-1934897_1280.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="subitem">
    <div class="text">  
     <h3>Some Text</h3>   
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Serg, that's exactly what I wanted to achieve :-)

Comment: Is there a way to align the text to the bottom right? When I set CSS  bottom: 0; and right: 0; the text dissappears from the pictures?

Comment: I would say use my code but add width:100%; text-alignment: right;